# Open Chrome on new tab with pinned tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to have Chrome open focus on a new tab when there are pinned tabs already?
By default it seems that Chrome always opens with focus on the first Pinned tab

The picture shows where I'd like focus when I open Chrome.

[image]

When I open Chrome, the selected tab is always the first one (far left, the orange icon)
I want it to open and have the focus automatically on the new tab (google.ca)

Comment: Try rephrasing your question - I don't follow what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is there anything new concerning this question? I need this so hard as well without installing a bloated extension :( I found this discussion, but without a solution either: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qUvvukV6B_Q EDIT: Finally found a good/clean/small/simple extension for it, see below

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful to you, if not there are similar apps listed [FLST Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajnianifcggmdojhnmjichjmnjpplcha)

**Overview:** Focus Last Selected Tab :: Provides natural tab ordering plus Options for tab-flipping, new tab focus, and new tab positioning

Comment: useful yes thank you. not quite what i'm looking for though.

Comment: Any of the 'Related' apps useful?

Answer (score 1):

Right click the "new tab" and pin it.  Then drag the pinned "new tab" to the far left.  Now the new tab will come up pinned first, then the remaining pinned tabs.

Comment: Problem is with this is that when I move that tab to a different web page, the last page will be what loads next time. I want the new tab to just be google.com

Yes, I could just click home before closing, but that's the little time saver I want to skip in the first place.